# Acts_as_taggable_on undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on

Rails 3.0.3

ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]

### acts-as-taggable-on (2.0.6)

i have bundle installed and rake db:migrated

I have the following in my gemfile:

```
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
```

and i have the following in my items controller

```
acts_as_taggable
```

I read the docs [here](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) and i have searched stack overflow fairly extensively but i am still getting the error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (undefined local variable or method `acts_as_taggable' for ItemsController:Class):
```

app/controllers/items_controller.rb:2:in `<class:ItemsController>'
  app/controllers/items_controller.rb:1:in`'

The only thing that I can see is that possibly i need to 'require' taggable somewhere (but this is not mentioned in the docs) is this likely to be the case? I was under the impression that rails3+ did not require requires... or have i got that wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `acts_as_taggable` goes in your **model** not in your **controller**:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Alias for <tt>acts_as_taggable_on :tags</tt>:
    acts_as_taggable
end
```

Hope this helps